# Scrapy: import item from .py file failes

Tags: python, import, module, scrapy

Scrapy beginner's question.

I've written a scrapy spider which i.a. imports a dictionary from another .py file – `postal_codes.py`. I've placed `postal_codes.py` in the same folder as the spider.

When I run `from postal_codes import postals` in the IDE, it works fine. However, when I execute the spider in Terminal (shell) I receive the following error,

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'postal_codes'
```

How do I correctly import a dictionary from another .py file when executed via Terminal?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15998654/7326714) does not solve my problem.

---

**Directory**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try with project name in front.

```
from PROJECT_FOLDER_PATH.postal_codes import postals
```

PROJECT_FOLDER_PATH is the folder name of your Scrapy project

Comment: I've added a screenshot from the directory. The project name is `london`, but `from london.postal_codes import postals` does not work. That is, same error is given.

Comment: I tried `from london.spiders.postal_codes import postals` and that worked! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Shouldn't do that? I'm quite new to programming and completely new to Scrapy, so if I made an obvious mistake, please let me know.

Comment: @LucSpan you should only put your spiders in `Spiders` folder  .... and put your all other files in same directory as `settings.py` ... BTW you can put contents of `postal_codes.py` in `settings.py` ...

Comment: So, how do you call it?  Using self.myFunctionName( stuff ) or myFunctionName( stuff )?

Comment: Also, I referenced your question in my question here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74870540/in-python-scrapy-with-multiple-projects-how-do-you-import-a-class-method-from  Is there a way to do your solution but from an entirely separate project?

Comment: @rom I replied on your question